# change ubuntu to be second OS (after Windows 10) in boot menu

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu via DVD onto a Windows 10 laptop.

During boot, Ubuntu is the default option, and Windows 10 is a menu option.

How do I make Windows 10 the default boot option please?

Comment: Oh. I'm not familiar with Lunix and don't know what grub is.

Comment: `grub` is basically that menu you were talking about.  By editing `/etc/default/grub` file in Ubuntu, you will be able to set which menu option you want to start by default. Follow the instructions given in the linked duplicate post. It's nothing scary or complicated, just edit a text file and run `sudo update-grub` for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks. It was the `sudo update-grub` I needed after making changes in the links above.